# Matlab TreeBagger Cost argument not working as it works with similar function fitensemble

Tags: classification, matlab, random-forest

The cost function of my TreeBagger class and fitensemble (Bag method) are both [0 8;1 0] for binary classification. The confusion matrix on fitensemble shows that the classfication tends to turn in the favor of the costy class (like [100 0; 20 80] favoring false negatives) but the same on TreeBagger does not hold. I have tried it on 3 datasets and TreeBagger seems to ignore the cost as I have omitted the cost argument and the confusion matrix is like when you dont give cost at all. Is there a Problem with my code or is it the TreeBagger? (BTW the problem is not misinterpretation of confusion matrix, it just doesn't work)

My Code

(TREEBAGGER WHICH DOES NOT WORK)

```
RF=TreeBagger(150,Xtrain,Ytrain,'oobpred','on','cost',[0 8;1 0])
```

(FITENSEMBLE WHICH WORKS)

```
Bag=(Xtrain,Ytrain,'Bag',150,'type','classification','cost',[0 8;1 0]);
```

Thank you for your help.